# How to troubleshoot a very simple application consuming high CPU?

Tags: java, android

I was reported about some performance issues on a app I'm currently developing. It's a quite simple application without very complex logic.

Opened on the main view without any user activity, it takes about 25% of the CPU (15% of "user" and 10% of "kernel") on a Samsung S5 device. There is a background network polling but I tried removing that and CPU usage is similar.

This is a trace output (no user activity, just app in foreground)

[image]

I'm not sure if this is normal but I found some references that it could be indicating a deadlock (due `java.lang.Object.wait` taking most of the time)

Do you see any obvious problema on my trace? How to better troubleshoot this?

I've seen much more complex apps using 2 or 3% of the CPU so there must be something I can improve.

Comment: Actually not Object.wait is taking a lot of time, but ZygoteInit, right?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure which of those indicators is more relevant. Maybe if you tell me which one provides more information, I could run a trace again sorting by that column

Comment: I think the ZygoteInit is a startup task from android. Are you sure that's not just the startup of your emulator and your app is actually running totally fine at 4.9%? Maybe you don't see any issues because there is none (it might be an issue with the user's phone?)

Comment: Problem is not on emulator but on a real device and this trace is not on app startup

Comment: Well then my answer to "How to better troubleshoot this" is "run and debug it on a emulator"